# How to diagnose crack on ceiling

Tags: ceiling

Today I woke up to a nice surprise, a crack and stain on my first floor ceiling. The damage is below the shower wall of the upstairs bathroom, so I'm thinking this could be water related.

I'm new at this and would love to hear some advice for how to start diagnosing this problem.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is clearly a split in your ceiling gypsum board. This could be caused from 1) moisture, 2) temperature, 3) settlement

1) Moisture is the most difficult to “track down”. If it’s sudden, like you indicate, it could be from a “new” user of the shower. Do you have guests? This could be a one time event.

You said “shower”, you did not say “tub/shower”. If it is a tub, it could be an unintended overflow problem...also probably a one time event.

2) If the shower space had been extra cold and extra hot water was turned on the floor, it could crack the floor.

3) For showers, I’d look closely at the joint between the wall and floor AND the joints between the walls. Any hairline crack will cause a problem.

Also, if the shower wall settled, from an extra heavy snow load, it could cause a crack.

Obviously, you’ll want to remove the shower valve cover and see if there’s a leak at the valve (be sure to turn the water on for awhile)...likewise at the shower head, door to wall fasteners, etc.

The leak could have been building for a long time, so check for even small leaks.

I’d isolate the drain line by plugging it and putting 2-3” of water in the bottom for 6-7 hours. If it leaks, then it’s not the drainline...

Remember, water will run a good distance (in the direction of least resistance) so you can’t just look at what is directly above the crack. I’d guess the leak is probably several feet away from the crack. The crack is just where there is a joint in the gypsum board which allows the moisture to drip through.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say your hunch is correct.

1. Look at the plumbing.

If you'd like more help, provide more information.

Comment: Thanks! How should I go about looking at the plumbing? What sort of information would be helpful for me to provide?

Comment: You should report the results of step 1, or any impediment to doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You’re going to have to repair the water damaged drywall anyway, so why not just cut a hole where’s it damaged to see what is causing it.

Comment: Because the plumbing may be readily accessible from elsewhere and cutting a hole requires repairing the hole. Right now, all that's needed is some taping.

Comment: isn't mold going to form on the wet sheetrock?

Comment: Not necessarily, and even if it does a little, it's not really a problem. (Mold isn't really dangerous in most cases, and a stain-blocking primer makes the stain go away.) Many a ceiling has been repaired without demolition.

Comment: Since it was a sudden change with discoloration I might poke a small 1/4" hole close to the stain and see if you can drain any water, but agree with isherwood that many times the leak can be fixed and retaping and texturing the area will be quick.